# SpEL in named-native-query

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I wrote the following piece of code, which is working:

```
@Query(value = "Select s.* from cost s where s.price1 = :#{#req.price1} and s.price2 = :#{#req.price2}", nativeQuery = true)
List<Cost> findNative(PriceQueryRequest req);
```

And now I need to use `orm.xml`, but when I try put the exact same string in XML like below:

```
<named-native-query name="Cost.findNative">
<query>
  <![CDATA[
    Select s.* from cost s where s.price1 = :#{#req.price1} and s.price2 = :#{#req.price2}
    ]]>
</query>
```

I'm getting the exception "QueryException: Space is not allowed after parameter prefix ':'"

My question is how to use SpEL in orm.xml?

I can't unwrap my DTO and send separate query params, the only way I have is through a DTO.